# How to count records in query result on SQLite3 using PHP

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

I need to make a query in my SQLite3 database using PHP and this is my code and it's working:

```
# Set access to data base...
$db = new SQLite3('./Data/myDB.sqlite');

# Set the query  ...
$q="SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE key = '123'";

# Prepare for the query ...
$stmt = $db->prepare($q);

# Execute the query ...
$results = $stmt->execute();
```

Now, how to count how many records there are in my result? Suggestions / examples?

Comment: quicker to search before you ask

Comment: Wow, nothing in the manual.  Would have expected `num_rows` or similar but seems to be missing.  You either need to loop result or `SELECT count(*) ...`

Comment: Note, you should be using prepared statements with bound parameters or else your query is open to SQL injection attacks: http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3stmt.bindvalue.php

Comment: @AbraCadaver Weird, right? I was thinking the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You could either do it in SQL or in PHP:

Change your SQL request to

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table WHERE key = 123
```

Or count rows in PHP ([taken from here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.sqlite3result.php)) :

```
$nrows = 0;
$result->reset();
while ($result->fetchArray())
    $nrows++;
$result->reset();
return $nrows;
```

Comment: `while($rows[] = $result->fetchArray()){} $count = counts($rows);` maybe.